# How can I show contravariant vector?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\phi : U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 \to M \subset \mathbb{R}^k$ be a parametrization of a surface M. Suppose $p \in M$ and (u,v) and $(\bar{u},\bar{v})$ are 2 sets of local coordinates around p. We know that any vector $\vec{w} \in T_p(M)$ can be represented by

$$\vec{w} = A^1 \frac{\partial\vec{\phi}}{\partial u} + A^2 \frac{\partial\vec{\phi}}{\partial v} = \bar{A^1} \frac{\partial\vec{\phi}}{\partial u}  + \bar{A^2} \frac{\partial\vec{\phi}}{\partial v} $$

Using the chain rule, show that $\vec{w}$ is a contravariant vector.

What I have so far is this:

Let $A^1 = \frac{dx^1}{dt}$ and $A^2 = \frac{dx^1}{dt}$

$\bar{A^1} = \frac{d\bar{x^1}}{dt} = \frac{d\bar{x^1}}{dx^1}\frac{dx^1}{dt}+\frac{d\bar{x^1}}{dx^2}\frac{dx^2}{dt}+...+\frac{d\bar{x^1}}{dx^n}\frac{dx^n}{dt} $= $A^1 \frac{d\bar{x^1}}{dx^1} + A^2 \frac{d\bar{x^1}}{dx^2}+...+A^n\frac{d\bar{x^1}}{dx^n}$

Is this correct and if so how can I change it to correct notation with $\phi$ and u,v

Comment: What is your definition of a contravariant vector?

Comment: let $(x^1,...,x^n)$ and $(\bar{x}^1,...,\bar{x}^n)$ be two coordinate systems in a neighborhood of a point $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$. an n-tuple $<A^1,...,A^n>$ constitutes the components of a contravariant vector at a point p if the components transform according to $\bar{A}^j = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial\bar{x}^j}{\partial x_{i}} A^{i}$

Comment: @Greg.Paul does that help?

Comment: You are almost there. Just replace your total derivatives wih partial derivatives, and you are done: the components $\bar{A}^{j}$ satisfy your definition.
If you want your original expression in terms of $u$ and $v$, just do the opposite transformation to get $A^{i}$ in terms of $bar{A}^{i}$ and substitute $A^{i}$, doing the replacements $x^{1}\to u$, $x^{2}\to v$, $\bar{x}^{1}\to \bar{u}$ and $\bar{x}^{2}\to\bar{v}$.